# What is the difference between these two types of declration in javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
var collection={one: 1, two: 2, three: 3};
```

because: When I loop through this using underscore.js

it gives me key as well value like this:

```
one
1
two
2
three
3
```

and

```
var collection=[{name:"gaurav"},{name:"ankit"},{name:"amit"}];
```

because: When I loop through this using underscore.js

it gives me index as well value like this:

```
gaurav
0
ankit
1
amit
2
```

Is there any difference between the above two declaration.

Comment: Well, you must be looping through it in a different manner, aren't you? Please show us the underscore code that you are using.

Comment: The first one (despite your variable name) is not a collection. Its an object that contains 3 properties.  The second is an array (a collection) that contains 3 elements, each element being an object with 1 property.

Comment: These create the two fundamental composite types in JavaScript. If you don't understand the difference, then you probably don't understand what they are individually, which means you probably just need to run through some basic JavaScript tutorials

Comment: The first is one single object; the second one is an array containing objects.

Comment: I recommend to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object .

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you have declared an *object* - when you iterate through this object, underscore is giving you each key-value pair found in it.

In the second case, you have declared an *array* (note the square brackets). Iterating through this gives you the index and value of each entry in the array.

Since the structures of arrays and objects are characterized by index-value and key-value respectively, iteration gets you the results you see - it shows you what is "inside" each data type.

Comment: Here's how you can get JavaScript to show you that your collections in fact are the types that @roni-choudhury mentioned: http://jsfiddle.net/qMMd9/

Comment: Also worth noting (since the OP didn't show how the loop was done) that *for..in* may return the values any order, not necessarily the order in which they appear in a literal, nor where added or in numeric or alphabetic order based on the property name. No particular order *at all*.